# Bluetooth with Android

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm new in android and I'm going to work with Bluetooth, but when I import bluetooth like the lines I express here:

```
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothServerSocket;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
```

my SDK can not realize android.bluetooth . In addition, I add all packages and devices from "Android SDK and AVD Manager" but I still have problem. Could you help me to know how can I solve this problem.
Thanks.

Comment: Which API level are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Taken from the developer website:

> To perform Bluetooth communication using these APIs, an application
>   must declare the BLUETOOTH permission. Some additional functionality,
>   such as requesting device discovery, also requires the BLUETOOTH_ADMIN
>   permission.

They import fine for me, perhaps you should run the software updater and ensure you've downloaded all the packages?

One last thing, the SDK cannot use the bluetooth package and you must test on a real device.

Comment: How is this related to the problem that he can't import the package?

Comment: I defined permissions already but I still have problem. My question is If I want to install all SDK's versions I should install them from "Android SDK and AVD Manager". Because I read that Android SDK 1 have not supported Bluetooth and I have to install the other SDK versions.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of development environment do you use ? These packages and classes are in **android.jar**

If you have Eclipse plugin and SDK and create a android project , you will have to project include the **android.jar** and you should not have this problem.

If your environment is different, make sure that android.jar is in your CLASSPATH. It will be under  **platforms\android-2.1** where your SDK is installed. (assuming you are using android 2.1)

Answer (score 0):

Open project properties, Android, Select your target

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, to solve the problem, upgrade the android min required android version :

project/properties/android -> target name,

and select at least API version 7 (android 2.1)
and of course add the bluetooth declarations in the manifest